# Getting long array separated by line break - how to parse? Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a function which gets an object, after that we decide the instance type.
...

```
for (String key: keys){
    Object tmp = bundle.get(key);
    if (tmp instanceof Boolean) {
...
...
```

I unexpectedly get a '\r\r\n' when instance type is long array. It doesn't throw exception, no errors in code. How can I parse it?

```
else if (tmp instanceof long[]){
    Log.e(TAG, "TODO la"); // TODO
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    sb2.append...
```

Thanks, Bela

Comment: the trim() function on a String will return the same Strign with all whitepaces and line breaks removed.

Comment: This approach looks bad though. Are you sure this is the best way, using bunch of `instanceof`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Where do you get `\r\r\n`? And if it occurs with `long[]` isn't it already parsed?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `trim()` method should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers, but the problem was originated from Logcats' 4096 line limit.